# 2x image not working on retina device

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an image with the following naming convention.
It always shows the non 2x version on retina device. 
I had removed cache images from derived data but still not showing.
It works if i explicitly set the imageNamed to "Back"
These are the images.
Back@2x.png
Back.png

```
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];
NSLog(@"back image height %f",backImage.size.height);
NSLog(@"back image width %f",backImage.size.width);

UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnBack setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height);
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(Click_On_Btn_Back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer here. You should not use the .png extension when using the imageNamed method. The correct x2 image will be chosen if both .png and @2x.png files exist and are added to the target. Also a VERY common problem people come across is the naming convention. 2X will not work. Make sure your images are actually Back@2x.png and not Back@2X.png . This also applies to ~ipad.png and @2x~ipad.png name conventions for iPad and iPad Retina respectively.

Comment: Also, you may want to go ahead and check the current scale if you are trying to use the iPhone4/5 simulator. CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

Comment: my code met all the requirements you talked about and using device -iphone 5.

Comment: Add more code please. We need to see how you are using this UIImage. Perhaps it is simply being scaled down/up rather than not being applied.

Comment: I just updated the code. It is showing the 20x20 image which is not 2x. 2x has 40x40.

Comment: Remove the .png from the @"Back.png" so it reads [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];

Comment: Another thought... are you positive the actual filename is Back@2x.png and not back@2x.png and was later renamed in Xcode to show Back@2x.png. Verify the name in Finder vs. in Xcode. I've seen this issue in the past where renaming a file in Xcode does not change the actual source file's name so it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Are you using the latest iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"];
```

Also, make sure both versions of the image are listed under Target->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources. If the @2x version is not, make sure when you import it you check the box "Copy into destination group's folder (if needed)."

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify `.png` in imageNamed: parameter.

Example: files should be names `Back.png` and `Back@2x.png`; Your code should be

```
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];
```

Comment: Omitting the suffix is bad practice. The code is correct and correctness doesn't smell, avoid such niches: `On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension.`

Answer (score 0):

This is just one approach, but you can get the path from the bundle:

```
// in this example, we load test.png from the bundle
NSString *pathToResource = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png"];
```

What makes this so convenient is that it not only automatically determines whether to use the @2x version of your image, but also when you have localized files, this provides the path the the file for the current user locale. This is handy since localized files are not in the main directory, but are rather in their own subfolders (for example, English localized files are in the @"en.lproj" subfolder), and calling them by name is a hassle because you need the full path. This method gets the path for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Keller's answer should work. are you sure that you are using png images.